# How to make extension persist on TinyCore emulated with qemu

Tags: qemu

I am emulating TinyCore on Qemu but I don't understand how to make my extension persistent between reboots.

I've read [this](http://wiki.tinycorelinux.net/wiki:persistence_for_dummies) guide about persistence and [this](http://www.linuceum.com/Distros/osInstallingTinyCore.php) about mounted mode but everything I do doesn't work and I keep losing my extension at each reboot.

I'm very noob, I understand why this happens but I am not able to do what I want.

**How can I save my extensions between each reboot**?

What I've tried so far:

1. Moving my extensions to `/tce/options` but I am not able to backup them because I can't find any partition
2. I've created a `.img` and passed it to qemu, tried to backup using `filetool.sh -b`, I've got no error but it doesn't worked.
3. Created a `.img` with an ext2 partition, mounted in `loop1` and passed it as boot parameter `tce=loop1`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use coreplus install to a virtual harddisk, with boot parameter `tce={hda}`

seems work now.